# Getting an azure project to start a hostname

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I have an azure project in visual studio.

It has a web role which is an MVC project in the same solution.

Currently when you start the project it will run as 'http://127.0.0.1:81/', however I would like it to run as 'http://localhost.somedomain.blah'.

I've looked in the project properties and had a quick search both on Google and specifically on SO but with no luck.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I take it you mean "... however I **would** like it to run as `http://localhost.somedomain.blah`"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - this is the expected behaviour of the Azure "compute emulator" that is started when you run an Azure project locally.

It's only when the project is actually uploaded to Azure that you get control of the URI. In particular it is difficult to stop the compute emulator using port 81.

Comment: That's what I figured. I guess for now I'll just continue manually changing the address in the browser each time.